# Why does `ffmpeg` depend on desktop-related packages?

Tags: apt, server, ffmpeg

I'm a sysadmin and I wanted to install `ffmpeg` and its libraries to my Ubuntu server as one of user's web-app requires it to transcode audio files.

But why does it depend on so many packages that aren't required for Ubuntu server? I see some X libraries, wayland, mesa drivers, nvidia libs, fontconfig, pango etc.

I obviously won't do something like `x11grab` on my server or "play" a video directly though.

```
~$ sudo apt install ffmpeg
[sudo] password for ahfas:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fontconfig i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-0.9 libdatrie1 libdc1394-22 libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgme0 libgomp1 libgraphite2-3 libgsm1 libharfbuzz0b libiec61883-0 libigdgmm11 libjack-jackd2-0 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblilv-0-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmysofa1
  libnorm1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpixman-1-0 libpostproc55 libraw1394-11 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common librubberband2 libsamplerate0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5
  libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5 libtwolame0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvpx6 libwavpack1 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwebp6 libwebpmux3 libx264-155
  libx265-179 libxcb-render0 libxcursor1 libxkbcommon0 libxss1 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc i965-va-driver-shaders libbluray-bdj libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev jackd2 libportaudio2 opus-tools libraw1394-doc librsvg2-bin serdi sndiod sordi speex opencl-icd libvdpau-va-gl1
  nvidia-vdpau-driver nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg fontconfig i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2
  libbs2b0 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-0.9 libdatrie1 libdc1394-22 libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgme0 libgomp1 libgraphite2-3 libgsm1 libharfbuzz0b libiec61883-0 libigdgmm11 libjack-jackd2-0 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblilv-0-0 libmp3lame0
  libmpg123-0 libmysofa1 libnorm1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpixman-1-0 libpostproc55 libraw1394-11
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librubberband2 libsamplerate0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3
  libswscale5 libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5 libtwolame0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvpx6 libwavpack1 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwebp6 libwebpmux3
  libx264-155 libx265-179 libxcb-render0 libxcursor1 libxkbcommon0 libxss1 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 va-driver-all
  vdpau-driver-all
0 upgraded, 107 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 237 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

While using `--no-install-recommends` would get rid most of the graphical-related packages (like X, wayland, nvidia drivers, for instance), I just curious on why would `ffmpeg` require those packages by default?

---

My Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: " But why does it depend on so many packages that aren't required for Ubuntu server?" which one? (almost) all are libraries. And what do you mean "for Ubuntu server" They are needed for ffmpeg.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` package is a set of tools for transcoding, streaming and playing of multimedia files including `ffmeg`, `ffplay`, `ffprobe` and `qt-faststart` ... Some of which require a graphical display environment ... Hence the dependencies you think are desktop environment related.

Comment: The method to specify packages required is a way to [re]use tools that already exist and are available in typical linux environments instead of making a huge package with everything necessary. This is typical for linux, and it helps you avoid creating doublets or multiplets of tools.

Comment: @Rinzwind For example, the X and wayland libs. Obviously, I wouldn't do something like `x11grab` on my server. I only need ffmpeg to convert audio/video files.

Comment: Try with `--no-install-recommends`

Comment: @muru, It still wants to install everything.

Comment: @Annahri then something's wrong with your system. I tried it on the Ubuntu 20.04 Docker image, and while it still wants `x11-common` and `xkb-data` and a few other X11 packages, it's not trying to install `x11grab` or `i965-va-driver` or a bunch of other packages with `--no-install-recommends`. And of course media transformation often involves text (e.g., subtitles), so font-related packages would be needed anyway.

Comment: @muru, Well, I just tested my Ubuntu 20.04 WSL, it does the same. https://pastebin.com/cDuiym5D

Comment: @Annahri, If you don't want those packages in your server, don't use ffmpeg there. Either use some other tool, or install ffmpeg somewhere else, in another computer or in a virtual machine, so that the program packages that you don't like are confined to the virtual machine (which can be turned off when you are not using ffmpeg).

Comment: Well the only course of action is to file a bugreport. The "why" part of this question is asking for an opinion and we can only answer with "because the package is set up this way" and there is no way to not install it if the package is set up to need it.  @muru my system doed the same as what you state using `--no-install-recommends`

Comment: @muru Ah, you're correct. I re-checked it again, and it no longer asking to install some of X packages and others.

Comment: *Some of which require a graphical display environment* --> no ffmpeg component requires a graphical environment. It is entirely CLI. To the OP, a lot of ffmpeg functionality is provided by external libraries,which have wrappers in ffmpeg. My full build for Windows links to 78 external libraries. But all of them are either statically linked or system libs, so it's just 'one' package. Won't be the case for shared builds.

Comment: @Gyan `ffmpeg` on Ubuntu appears to be a mtapackage that includes [ffplay](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ffplay.1.html) and others by default(*although might not be needed for server users*) please see also [Compile FFmpeg for Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Hi @Raffa, please make it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ffmpeg`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/ffmpeg) on Ubuntu 20.04(*as well as other releases*) is a meta package that includes [`ffplay`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ffplay.1.html) and other components(*although might not be wanted/needed by server users*) which require a graphical display environment ... Hence the dependencies you think are desktop environment related.

Unfortunately, server users have no choice but to accept and live with these extra dependencies at the time being when installing the pre-compiled package(s) from the official Ubuntu repositories.

They, however, can omit the `ffplay` and x11grab dependencies(*e.g. `libsdl2-dev`, `libva-dev`, `libvdpau-dev`, `libxcb1-dev`, `libxcb-shm0-dev` and `libxcb-xfixes0-dev`*) if they choose to [compile **FFmpeg** from source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: so we can install normal dependencies and extract ffmpeg executable from ubuntu package? Good idea, will try.